# Exact pattern match in r

Tags: regex, r, pattern-matching

I am reading files from a folder using List.files but i want to read only specific files to be read. I have files like below.

```
D420000900100hour.1-4-2001.31-12-2001
D420000700600hour8.1-1-2001.31-12-2004
D420000500150hour.1-1-2001.31-12-2004
```

Notice here i have "hour" and "hour8". I want to only list files containing exactly "hour".

```
 files <- list.files(pattern = "hour")
```

With this piece of code however it returns files with both "hour" and "hour8". I am trying to use ^ and $. but they dont seem to work with "pattern".

How do i do this.

Comment: I guess you want to select `hour` followed by `.` then use `pattern='hour\\.'`

Comment: @akrun, it was simple. that was it. thanks !

Comment: Or you may also try `files <- list.files(pattern = "hour\\b")` to match  an `hour` that is not followed by a word character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the example, we can change the pattern argument to `hour` followed by `.`

```
list.files(pattern = "hour\\.")
```

Or 'hour' followed by any character that is not a number

```
list.files(pattern = "hour[^0-9]")
```